# Issue with driver for Radeon 3000 video on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: radeon

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with an Asus motherboard with an Nvidia 3000 graphics chip. It was running fine in 2d but not 3d. I have a couple of Nvidia R9 380 cards, so I tried to install one on the machine. Hardware install went fine, but when I tried to get it running on Ubuntu the drivers didn't work, so I pulled it out. Now the issue is that the 3000 is not getting an associated driver. Result of `lshw -c video` is:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: RS780L [Radeon 3000]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 5
bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe8f0000-fe8fffff memory:fe700000-fe7fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

I tried various Nvidia drivers but none are compatible, and the kernel is also not providing a driver. I've removed all Nvidia drivers but the issue remains. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I finally got the kernel driver to load:

```
*-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: RS780L [Radeon 3000]
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      physical id: 5
      bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
      resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe8f0000-fe8fffff memory:fe700000-fe7fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

But it seems there's still an issue with the Xsession video driver as the session is still not loading.

I've checked `.xsession.errors` but I'm not seeing anything there that gives me a clue:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/fred/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/fred
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=fred
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/fred
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/fred
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/home/fred/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US:en
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=ubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=fred
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/fred/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/fred/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
```

I've also checked /var/log/messages, but no hints there.

Currently the only display manager that seems to function is lightdm and there I get the login prompt, enter my password, brief black screen and back to the login page. I've tried all the fixes I could find for the login loop issue, but none worked. It seems that the display manager can load, but then when it tries to load the X session it breaks. I've also tested with another user account on the machine with the same result. Testing with VNC the session loads fine.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to sort this out with the following:

sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
reboot
enjoy getting your life back! :-)

Hope this helps someone else